# MongoDB document validation fail

Tags: mongodb, validation, document

Trying to test the validation of the document below:

```
db.createCollection("Users", {
  validator: {
    $and: [
      {
        Uid: {
          $type: "string", 
          $exists: true  
        }
      },
      {
        "Doc.Name": { $type: "string", $exists: true},
        "Doc.Files": [
           { 
              "$ref": { $in: [ "fs.files" ] },
              "$id": { $type: "objectId", $exists: true },
              "$db": { $in: [ "mydb" ] }
           }
        ]
       }
    ]
  }
})
```

With command of insertion:

```
db.Users.insert({
   Uid: "ABCDFE123m", 
   Doc: { 
     Name: "12hgf123", 
     Files: [
       { 
         $ref:"fs.files", 
         $id: ObjectId("5910e46b24f3f7057c4088a8"), 
         $db: "mydb"
       }, 
       {
         $ref:"fs.files", 
         $id: ObjectId("4010e46b24f3f7057c408806"), 
         $db: "mydb"
        }
     ]
   }
})
```

I get the following error:

```
WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 121,
                "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
        }
})
```

Enable to validate the document insertion. Someone can help me? Look like i forget something.

Regards

Comment: Don't use referential integrity in a NoSQL database.

Comment: Any suggestion on how i can validate the document?

Comment: You are trying to use a non-relational database (document oriented) to implement relations in it. I can help you solve your problem, but this is not a problem you should be having in the first place. Instead of solving this problem, think how you could organize your data so you don't have joins and don't have relations.

Comment: The main reason you should not be doing this is because Mongo does not offer the guarantees that are required to keep data consistent across multiple collections in the presence of relations. If you want relations, use a relational database that provides such guarantees (e.g: ACID).

Comment: I explain what is my need. I have users collection and each user can download one or more files. So i want to create a link between the user and it's downloded file. Do you know how to integrate files in mongodb collection which is different to the GridFS default collections fs.files and fs.chunks. My Main problem is here if it is possible to integrate these files in users collection reference will be use.